# Drive two different browsers in one GebReportingSpec?

Tags: grails, functional-testing, geb

I'm using geb and spock for functional tests in my Grails 2.3.7 app. The app allows real-time interaction between users, which I'd like to test automatically.

Does anyone know how, or if it's possible, to run two different browsers in one Spec? For example, see the pseudo code below for how I imagine this working in a perfect world.

```
@Stepwise
class ChatPageSpec extends GebReportingSpec {

    def "login with chrome"() {
    }

    def "login with firefox"() {
    }

    def "send chat request with chrome"() {
    }

    def "accept chat request with firefox"() {
    }

    def "send hello with chrome"() {
    }

    def "receive hello with firefox"() {
    }
}
```

Running the tests in parallel as Craig describes (http://www.objectpartners.com/2013/11/14/parallel-grails-functional-tests-with-geb-and-gradle/) looked promising, but if I understand it correctly, the parallel tests would use different app instances, which won't work. Plus, @Stepwise or something similar would have to keep the browsers in sync.

I also checked out the poly driver plugin (http://grails.org/plugin/poly-driver), but it looks like it's designed for one browser per Spec.

Ken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that you will need to handcraft something for this.

There is [an example](https://github.com/alxndrsn/geb-multibrowser) of achieving this which was once posted to Geb mailing list. I have never used it myself but the code looks reasonable. It feels like you'll want to use `MultiBrowserGebSpec` and override `createBrowserMap()`.

You can create driver instances by hand and then set it on browsers instances using [`setDriver()`](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/api/geb/Browser.html#setDriver%28WebDriver%29). Another way would be to have different config files for different browsers which you would load using [`getConf()`](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/api/geb/ConfigurationLoader.html#getConf%28java.lang.String%29) and pass to `Browser` constructor. Yet another one would be to have different environments for different browsers in one `GebConfig.groovy` and use different `ConfifgurationLoader`s created using [the constructor that accepts environment name](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/api/geb/ConfigurationLoader.html#ConfigurationLoader%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Thanks, @erdi. I'm marking this as the answer because if you don't know, I doubt anyone else will. Once I get it working, I'll push to a new repo under my github account.

Comment: I didn't realize the framework would run two browser instances in isolation, so it was not necessary to use two different browsers. However, the end solution took me longer than I expected. See [my working example](https://github.com/kensiprell/geb-multiple-window-test).

Comment: Any updates on this topic? Would be nice to have something like the protractor config `multiCapabilities` to start multiple Browser instances and run the same tests on them in parallel